# Adding new vertex in a graph in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, graph, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am using Spark in Scala. I want to create a graph and update the graph   dynamically.

I have done this with the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object firstgraph {
  def addVertex(
    sc: SparkContext,
    vertexRDD: RDD[(Long(String,Int))],
    name: String,
    age: Int,
    counter:Long): RDD[(Long, (String, Int))] = {
    val newVertexArray = Array((counter, (name, age)))
    val newVertexRdd: RDD[(Long, (String, Int))] = sc.parallelize(newVertexArray)
    newVertexRdd ++ vertexRDD
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("firstgraph")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val vertexArray = Array(
      (1L, ("Alice", 28)),
      (2L, ("Bob", 27)),
      (3L, ("Charlie", 65)),
      (4L, ("David", 42)),
      (5L, ("Ed", 55)),
      (6L, ("Fran", 50)))

    val edgeArray = Array(
      Edge(2L, 1L, 7),
      Edge(2L, 4L, 2),
      Edge(3L, 2L, 4),
      Edge(3L, 6L, 3),
      Edge(4L, 1L, 1),
      Edge(5L, 2L, 2),
      Edge(5L, 3L, 8),
      Edge(5L, 6L, 3))

    var vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, (String, Int))] = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
    var edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)
    var graph: Graph[(String, Int), Int] = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)
    graph.vertices.filter { case (id, (name, age)) => age > 30 }.collect.foreach {
      case (id, (name, age)) => println(s"$name is $age")
    }
    var x = 0
    var counter = 7L
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
    while (x == 0) {
      println("Enter Name")
      name = Console.readLine
      println("Enter age")
      age = Console.readInt
      vertexRDD = addVertex(sc, vertexRDD, name, age, counter)
      graph = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)
      graph.vertices.filter { case (id, (name, age)) => age > 30 }.collect.foreach {
        case (id, (name, age)) => println(s"$name is $age")
      }
      counter = counter + 1
      println("want to enter more node press 0 for yes and 1 for no ")
      x = Console.readInt
    }
  }
}
```

This program is adding a new vertex in the graph but computing the graph again and again whenever the new vertex is inserted. I wish to do it without recomputing the graph.

Comment: graphx uses `RDD` under cover. You should use `persist`or it's alias `cache` to avoid recalculations.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Spark RDDs are not designed for fine-grained updates. All the operations on RDDs are about changing the whole RDD.

I would first recommend that you re-think your approach and try to use RDDs as they are designed. For example many common algorithms are designed for running on a single machine. Like Quicksort. You cannot implement Quicksort on RDDs unchanged, by swapping just two elements in each step. It would waste the potential of the distributed system to do many things in parallel. Instead you need to re-design the algorithm to take advantage of the parallelism.

That may not be applicable to your case, and you may really need to do point updates, such as in your example. In this case you are probably better off using a different backend. HBase and Cassandra are designed for point updates, as are all the other SQL and no-SQL databases. So is Neo4j if you need a graph database.

But one last thing to check before leaving Spark is [IndexedRDD](https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd). It is a kind of RDD that is designed for point updates. It was born as part of GraphX so it may be a good fit for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code for adding bunch of vertices to an existing graph.Here inputGraph is my existing graph which is predefined as global variable and is created before with some other function. This piece of code only adds vertices to that. Here rdd variable is my collection whose value is converted to Long and is used as vertex ids and is added to the graph.

```
def addVertex(rdd: RDD[String], sc: SparkContext, session: String): Long = {
val defaultUser = (0, 0)
rdd.collect().foreach { x =>
  {
    val aVertex: RDD[(VertexId, (Int, Int))] = sc.parallelize(Array((x.toLong, (100, 100))))
    gVertices = gVertices.union(aVertex)
  }
}
inputGraph = Graph(gVertices, gEdges, defaultUser)
inputGraph.cache()
gVertices = inputGraph.vertices
gVertices.cache()
val count = gVertices.count
println(count);

return 1;
```

}